# Angular: How to set parameters of dialog-component in .open()?

Tags: angular, parameters, constructor, dialog, components

Dialog-Component:

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) 
  public data: any, 
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>,
  @Optional() public dialogtitle: string ) {}
```

Calling part:

```
openMyDialog(somedata: string){
    const myDialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {data: somedata});
   }
```

How can I put data for optional parameter "dialogtitle" in there?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using angular material?

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>,
  @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogtitle: string ) {}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I already have the constructor as you can see in my post.
I need the according call